# Java initial values and array access basic understanding - unusual output

Tags: java, arrays, queue

I was writing a class to practice my data structures (Queue specifically) and I came across something that was quite odd. I initialize a variable (int) to ZERO on the class and later try to use that variable to place items in an array. When I run the program I get strange output.

```
public class QueueTest {

public static int[] myArr = new int[10];
static int currIndex = 0; ///// This variable is set to ZERO, used to keep track of where I am in the queue

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printArray(); // print initial array
    Queue(1);   // Add integer to list
    Queue(2);
    Queue(3);
    Queue(4);
    printArray(); // print resulting array
}

// place at end of queue
public static void Queue(int number){
if(currIndex >= QueueTest.myArr.length-1)
    resize();
    QueueTest.myArr[currIndex] = number;
    currIndex++;
}
// print the array      
public static void printArray(){
    for(int index : QueueTest.myArr){
        System.out.print(QueueTest.myArr[index]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
public static void resize(){} //to-do

public boolean leftShift(){} //to-do

public void findCurrentIndex(){} //to-do

} // end of class
```

When I run this program I get the following output:

0000000000

2340111111

But if I change the value of currIndex to 1, then everything adds fine to the array fine, just starting at the second position.

0000000000

0123400000

Can someone explain why this would be so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your print method is wrong:

```
for(int index : QueueTest.myArr){
    System.out.print(QueueTest.myArr[index]);
}
```

This is the [for each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html), so you don't get the indeces but the actual values of your array. So you want to do this:

```
for(int value: QueueTest.myArr){
    System.out.print(value);
}
```

Or regular for:

```
for(int i = 0; i < QueueTest.myArr.length; i++){
    System.out.print(QueueTest.myArr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Bah! I knew it was something I was overlooking. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1):

Your print method is bad. Also use proper indentation for your code, it makes it more readable.

Change

```
// print the array      
    public static void printArray(){
        for(int index : QueueTest.myArr){
            System.out.print(QueueTest.myArr[index]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

to

```
     // print the array      
    public static void printArray(){
        for(int index : QueueTest.myArr){
            System.out.print(index);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Comment: If OP did that then method `Queue` won't be able to add any `int` inside its array.